# Быстро узнать цвет пикселя на экране, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, обработка-изображений

Мне нужно быстро узнавать цвет пикселя на экране и реагировать на его изменение. Я работаю на Linux, Fedora. Как это можно сделать быстро на Python? Я пробовал использовать **`pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor()`** но 5-7 проверок в секунду для меня слишком медленно. Как можно это реализовать так, чтобы скорость обработки была выше? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если делать «быстро и тупо», я бы взял ffmpeg с x11grab и читал бы пиксели из его stdout

Comment: Наверное, я немножко опоздал, но библиотека [mss](https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss) позволяет захватить часть экрана и вроде бы довольно быстрая (на моём линуксе где-то до 7000 захватов в секунду получается)